# Talk to any static IP on network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

This may be an easy networking question. I have a device that always has a static IP address (DHCP is not allowed). This address can change depending on the user's need. I want to use a router for two other devices to be able to talk to this device. I don't want to have to change the configuration of the router every time some one changes the static IP on the device.

So router will be set up to DHCP starting at 192.168.1.100 My pc and another device(2) will lease ip's from the router.  PC will be over WIFI and device(2) will be hardwired. The device(3) with the static IP will be 10.118.205.143 How do I set up the router so device 3 can talk to the PC and device 2?

Comment: "every time some one changes the static IP on the device" Don't let people change the *static* IP...

Comment: normally this is handled by referring to the device with its dns name instead of IP.  ping <pc name> and it automatically finds the IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a router with DHCP at `192.168.1.x` range, you most likely need to choose a static IP **in** this range. (Or change DHCP to `10.118.205.x` if possible. Remember to exclude this static IP from DHCP IPs.

After you do this, you can simply plug in this device with static IP and let all devices talk to each other.

Be very careful when you choose static IPs on a DHCP network, if this static IP get changed to an IP in use, it may trigger a conflict and mess things up.

A better way to solve this would be setting MAC-IP binding on your router, which gives clients static IPs automatically (like DHCP). You will need all clients physical MAC addresses to do this.